# WEKA: What does the number after the '/' represent in these leaves?

Tags: weka, decision-tree

```
"0(607.0/60.0)"
"1(149.0/14.0)"
```

I know that 607 and 149 represent the total number of examples covered by each leaf.
I want to know what the numbers "60" and "14" after the '/' represent?

Answer (score 3):

The second number is the number **(weight)** of those instances that are **misclassified**.

Answer (score 0):

> The first number is the total number of instances (weight of instances) reaching the leaf. The second number is the number (weight) of those instances that are misclassified.

https://weka.wikispaces.com/What+do+those+numbers+mean+in+a+J48+tree%3F

Answer (score 0):

[For sample dataset](https://www.cs.vassar.edu/~cs366/data/weka_files/vote.arff%20Vote.arff%20in%20Weka)

Decision tree result:

> physician-fee-freeze = n: democrat (253.41/3.75).

First number indicated the number of correct things that reach that node. ( in this democrats) and the second number after “/” shows number of incorrect things that reach that node ( in this case republicans)

Total number of instances:

> 435 Total number of no (also integral number of correct things): 253
>   Probability of having no:
>
> 253/435 = 0.58

Total number of missing data:

> 11 Total number of times where it is coming with “no”: 8 Probability:
>   8/11 = 0.72

Total probability that missing data could be no:

> 0.58 X 0.72 = 0.42

Total number of correct things:

> 253+0.42 = 253.42 ~ 253.41

The number after the “/”shows number of incorrect things that reach that node. Now if you see this data it has five incorrect instances where “republican” is the result while “physician fee freeze” is “n” (or “?”)

Those five can be split as following: Total number incorrect instances with “n” : 2 Total number incorrect instances with “?”: 3

Similar formula:

> 2+(253/435)*3=3.75